# ASP.NET Socketing under medium security level

Tags: asp.net, security, sockets, tcp

I am trying to open a TCP connection to a server's specified port to see if the server is down and display that to users. I wonder if there is a work around to do that under medium level security since I am using a shared hosting enviorment and I dont think the hosting company would allow me to increase the security level to high or full.

Comment: How are you opening the socket? Are you using a third party tool?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman no, I am using TCPclient class

Comment: Have you tried applying the [SocketPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.socketpermission%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to allow access? There is an example of how to apply permissions on the linked page.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman no luck with it :(

Comment: What was the original error and the current error? What port are you trying to connect to?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman Security Error, it is trying to get the security for Socketing but failed since the security level is being set to Medium which forbits any socketing outside of the current domain. I guess I will have to find another way out

Comment: You could do this on the client side.